# Angular 4.3 HttpClient Multiple Authorization

Tags: angular, angular-http, angular-http-interceptors, angular-http-auth

I have a question about HttpClientModule, how can i use it for multiple Authorization, because when use HttpInterceptor Provider, it can only use in one case for example:

- Api 1 has token A
- Api 2 has token b

How can i use HttpClient for case above, because it only provide like this:

{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ApiInterceptor, multi: true }

Hope to have discussion with everyone.

Answer (score 1):

> You can chain multiple interceptors and it will be called in order you
>   specify in providers array of NgModule.

Comment: yep @Rahul Singh, but i think multiple chain is only one case, you can't use it for multiple case, i can't find documents about how to duplicate httpclient.

Comment: @TSL why do you want to duplicate the httpclient

Comment: because in this case, you interact with your api, and sometime you can interact with youtube or facebook, and you must create each one to add access_token to this.

Comment: check this if it might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/45987366/2708210